# Merge [setjmp] into [longjmp]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

These tags describe a complementary pair of C functions, and most questions tagged with one are also tagged with the other.

[longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longjmp) is the more popular, at 96 questions tagged vs 69, and has the more fleshed-out wiki, so it seems like the obvious choice for the merge target.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely agree.  The functions are two sides of the same coin, and can only be used together.

Most questions that use either use both tags already, and [longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longjmp) already has a tag wiki.

For example, the only reason I only tagged [setjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setjmp) on [What software-visible processor state needs to go in a jmp_buf on an x86-64 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544505/what-software-visible-processor-state-needs-to-go-in-a-jmp-buf-on-an-x86-64-proc) and not also [longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longjmp) is the 5-tag limit and keeping x86 + x86-64 was more useful.

I don't have 5 rep in the tag yet, so I couldn't propose adding setjmp as a synonym of longjmp.  Someone should [go do that](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/longjmp/synonyms) (unless there's a different procedure for tag merges).

Answer (score 2):

## [setjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setjmp) ← [longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longjmp)

Clearly, there do not need to be separate tags for each of these, since they refer to the same topic. They should be merged together under a single tag.

We have to choose one of them as the primary tag. Others have argued/assumed that [longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longjmp) needs to be the primary tag because it is the more widely used tag, with a better excerpt. However, the wiki can be easily moved, and tag synonyms take care of frictionlessly redirecting users to a new tag. So, I've decided that the primary tag should be [setjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setjmp), since that's the name of the header file (`setjmp.h`) that provides these functions in C.

Comment: "longjmp" is usually what I'd say if I was going to mention them, e.g. as an example of something that can break assumptions, or something other than C++ exceptions that can do funky stuff with the stack pointer.  But a google search shows that setjmp gets mentioned the same amount, and on `site:stackoverflow.com` there are 3000 hits for setjmp vs. 2930 for longjmp.  So I guess that's fine, maybe other people think of "setjmp" as the primary thing, and your point about the header name is good.

Comment: Note that they're synonyms, @Peter, so even if someone tries to use [longjmp], that'll still work just fine.

Comment: True.  My concern is only how it looks in the list of tags.  We have a tag for [context-switch], not [context-save]. (And a [context] tag with a couple random uses about other things).  Err, and we also have a separate tag for [context-switch*ing*].  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-switch vs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-switching; should probably also be synonyms.  But anyway, setjmp is fine, this isn't a real objection, more a digression about how *I* think about things.